# Why the output of grep command with following patterns is like that?

Tags: grep

Suppose I have both `kkk and k?k` words in a text file named `file1.txt`

I have to list both the words `kkk k?k` so I have given the following command

```
$grep k?k
```

but only `k?k` word is listed but not `kkk`

Here I haven't escaped the meaning of special character. so both the words should be displayed right?

Comment: In `grep` `?` is not a single wild character. In grep a single wild character is `.` Use `grep k.k` instead. Alternatively you can use `-E` option for extended regex `grep -E k?k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confusing `grep` with `egrep`:

```
$ cat 2
k?k
kkk
$ grep 'k?k' 2
k?k
$ egrep 'k?k' 2
k?k
kkk
```

Grep uses the basic regular expression syntax by default.  From the manual:

> In  basic  regular  expressions the metacharacters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the  backslashed   versions  \?, +, {, \|, (, and ).

So let's now try:

```
$ grep 'k\?k' 2
k?k
kkk
```

which is probably what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You're using plain grep, which uses basic regular expressions instead of extended ones. With basic regexes, you need to *escape* special characters to use their special meaning (see [POSIX basic + extended REs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

So either escape the question mark

```
grep "k\?k" file.txt
```

or use egrep

```
egrep k?k file.text
```